# Typescript Error: TS2314: Generic type 'ElementRef<T, any>' requires 2 type argument(s)

Tags: angular, typescript, compiler-errors, angular6

I'm using an Angular 5.x template, but I upgrade it to Angular 6 using https://update.angular.io/ guide. 
Now I have this error in my constructor

```
Typescript Error: TS2314: Generic type 'ElementRef<T, any>' requires 2 type argument(s)
```

My Code:

```
import { Component, Input, Output, EventEmitter, ElementRef, HostListener }          from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'sidebar',
  templateUrl: './sidebar.component.html'
})

export class SidebarComponent {

    @HostListener('document:click', ['$event'])
  clickout(event) {
    if(!this.eRef.nativeElement.contains(event.target)) {
          this.hideMobileSidebar.emit(true);
    }
  }

  constructor(private eRef: ElementRef) {
  }

...
```

I don't have this error in previous Angular version 5.

What was the change? I don't understand the docs :( https://angular.io/api/core/ElementRef

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fix the problem.

What I did was just run `npm i @angular-cli --save` and it changed from version 6.0.7 to 6.0.8, I also updated it globally. Then I run `ng update @angular/cli` but it doesn't change anything in my package.json. Now I can use `ElementRef` alone, or `ElementRef<HTMLElement>` or `ElementRef<HTMLElement, any>`, EVERYTHING WORKS NOW. I don't understand what angular-cli has to do with my tslint or typescript install, but thats the only thing I did.

Comment: The CLI is used to compile the project. Maybe it wasn't clearing the compiled cache properly.

Answer (score 6):

They've changed the `nativeElement` property from `any` to a [generic type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html).

If you want the quickly fix, then change `eRef: ElementRef` to `eRef: ElementRef<any>` which is the same as in previous versions.

This change means you can now define the class type for the DOM element that is being referenced. This will assist in TypeScript compiling to enforce that type, and also IDE auto-complete features.

There are many different class types, but the base class [Element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element) is used for most DOM elements. If you know it's going to be a `<input>` element you can use [HTMLInputElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement) as an example.

In your example the component is injecting it's DOM element for the constructor. Which would be a generic [HTMLElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement). So the code would be updated like this:

```
constructor(private eRef: ElementRef<HTMLElement>) {
     const title = eRef.nativeRef.title;
     // ^^^ the above title property is now verified by TypeScript at compile-time
}
```

Comment: I still have the same error `TS2314: Generic type 'ElementRef<T, any>' requires 2 type argument(s).`with `ElementRef<HTMLElement>` or `ElementRef<any>`

I don't know what I'm doing wrong u_u

Maybe I have the wrong version of Typescript? I have version 2.7.2

Comment: Make sure you have `import ElementRef from '@angular/core'` and that you're not importing from another module by mistake.

Comment: something is weird here because, as the error states, `ElementRef<T, any> requires 2 arguments.`  I can't find any documentation about what the second argument is supposed to be, but using "any" does work.....so you can say    `eRef: ElementRef<HTMLElement, any>;`    and that does work, i just am not sure what the "any" means in this context

Comment: @cmaroney I'm not running the latest Angular code on my current project. So I have to go to GitHub and look at the source, but on GitHub it takes only 1 argument. So I don't understand this either. Can you look at the source in the node_moduels as to why this extra argument is there?

Comment: I encountered this problem too. The easiest thing to do is to declare the type to be `any`. It's not a fix, but it's good enough for now. This looks like a problem in the tslint, since the code will compile and run normally, even with the error.

Comment: I don't know what I do, but the problem now is gone. What I did was update @angular-cli and it changed from 6.0.7 to 6.0.8 globally and locally, then I run `ng update @angular/cli`but It doesn't change anything.  
Now I can use `ElementRef` alone, or `ElementRef<HTMLElement>` or `ElementRef<HTMLElement, any>`, EVERYTHING WORKS NOW.
I can't understand what Angular-cli has to do with my tslint or typescript install, but thats the only thing I did. Thanks everyone.

Comment: @FrancoVP that is very strange. I would recommend that you clean your npm cache and do a fresh `npm install` just to make sure everything is good.