# generic type ElementRef<T, any> requires 2 type arguments angular 6

Tags: angular, elementref

I am using **ElementRef** to access DOM elements, but I am getting an error,

> generic type ElementRef requires 2 type arguments angular 6

This is code

**Import**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, ElementRef, Renderer2, AfterViewInit, ViewChild, ChangeDetectorRef, OnDestroy  } from '@angular/core';
```

**Code**

```
@ViewChild("transDtls") transModal: ElementRef;
```

The above code is the syntax I have seen in most sites, I have tried using this way

```
@ViewChild("transDtls") transModal: ElementRef<HTMLElement, any>;
```

which I saw in other site, it solved error in IDE, but I`m getting error in console while ng serve

> ERROR in
>   src/app/view/menu/transactions/transactions.component.ts(39,41): error
>   TS2707: Generic type 'ElementRef' requires between 0 and 1 type
>   arguments.

Because of this I couldn't use **ElementRef**, Kindly help I`m new to angular.

Comment: Are you getting two errors ? Check where you import `ElementRef` from, be sure to have no duplicates and post the current error. `ElementRef`doesn't need to be typed when used.

Comment: I have given import above, there are no duplicates, two different errors based on scenario, which I have described above..

Comment: there shouldn't be any problem try to clear your cache ```npm cache clean --force``` and run again.

Comment: Please use a [mcve] on https://stackblitz.io to reproduce your error

Comment: Should I user @ViewChild("transDtls") transModal: ElementRef; or @ViewChild("transDtls") transModal: ElementRef<HTMLElement, any>;

Comment: Because this gives error while writing in IDE @ViewChild("transDtls") transModal: ElementRef;

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Typescript Error: TS2314: Generic type 'ElementRef<T, any>' requires 2 type argument(s)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50704880/typescript-error-ts2314-generic-type-elementreft-any-requires-2-type-argu)