# ElementRef arguments expecting in Angular

Tags: angular

I'm working with angular version 8.3.22
While I' using the "elementRef" it's asking to have 2 arguments. So I had seen its definition. As per it I had provided as "elementRef" but still its throwing an error.

In core library I observed as error line under the class.

The exact error throwing in console is :
"error TS2707: Generic type 'ElementRef' requires between 0 and 1 type arguments."

I had found the same query in stackoverflow in the below link :
[Typescript Error: TS2314: Generic type 'ElementRef<T, any>' requires 2 type argument(s)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50704880/typescript-error-ts2314-generic-type-elementreft-any-requires-2-type-argu)

Tried the same solution but still I'm facing the problem.

Sample images :
[image: Error in core library image]

[image: Error in description ts file]

Comment: `ElementRef<HTMLElement, any>` -> `ElementRef<HTMLElement>`

Comment: Why I got -3 to my problem ?

Comment: @Z.Bagley , Thanks for reply. If I use as you suggested its throwing compilation error.

Comment: Probably got -3 due to poor screen shot images and the fact that there is no actual question (though I won't upvote, I don't think you deserve a down vote here). Try posting your new compilation error with a copy/paste of the code, what you've researched and tried to fix, and any other relevant info with an actual question! Check out the https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for more details on how to write a good question to avoid those downvotes next time!

Comment: @Z.Bagley updated with exact error please check once. "error TS2707: Generic type 'ElementRef' requires between 0 and 1 type arguments."

Comment: Have you tried to follow the previous instructions? Delete node_modules, package-lock.json, and perform a fresh `npm install`? It may be something is cached.

Answer (score 0):

It's a typescript error, ElementRef accepts up to 1 type arguments. You can refer [this](https://angular.io/api/core/ElementRef) angular doc for more details.

Replace this:

```
@ViewChild('mybtn',{static:true}) myvarible: ElementRef<HTMLElement, any>
```

with this:

```
@ViewChild('mybtn',{static:true}) myvarible: ElementRef<HTMLElement>
```

Comment: Tried with that one argument too. But still throwing error.